# How to blit only those tiles that are in player vision zone

Tags: python, pygame

#### Description

I was making a 2d platformer and I have runned into the problem

I already checked this answer: [Blitting a Pygame Tile-map Efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963775/blitting-a-pygame-tile-map-efficiently) but I don't use `camera`, I use veriables `cx` and `cy`.

#### Problem

So more bigger is the map, slower the game goes. And my maps is currently small compared of size that I want make playeble maps, but my game already drop 5 fps. So the game will be very slow if I make the playable size maps.

#### Code

So my map code is very simple. Here is some:
`pos = [(150, 300), (180, 330)...]`
Then in the loop I convert this position list into the `rects` so I can make collision, then make it follow the camera and draw tiles in the same time:

```py
p.clear()
for a in range(len(pos)):
    p.append(pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 50), (pos[a][0] - cam.x, pos[a][1] - cam.y, 30, 30)))
```

#### What i tried

So I thought to check every tile distance from player and blit only those that are in player in vision zone, but I will need to check every tile so it will not work (I already tried).

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: What do you mean by not using camera and `cx`, `cy` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all of the tiles into a matrix so that their position in the matrix correlates to where they would appear in-game. Then, based on the position of the camera and the size of the screen, iterate only through the tiles in the matrix that would be viewable and blit them to the screen.

For example,
Say every tile is 5 by 5 pixels,
the screen is 200 by 200 pixels, and
the map is 1500 by 500 pixels.

The tilemap matrix would be 300 by 100 pixels which is a fifth scale of the map because every tile is 5 by 5 pixels.

If the camera (which let's say is in the top left of the screen) is at (120,45), then the box from x = 120, y = 45 to x = 320, y = 245 (added 200 because of screen width and height) includes all the tiles that must be blitted.

Then divide these numbers by 5 to account for the difference in scale between the map and the tilemap to get the indexes for the needed tiles.

```
tile_size = 5  # Width and height of tiles in pixels

min_y = camera_y // tile_size
max_y = (camera_y + screen_height) // tile_size

min_x = camera_x // tile_size
max_x = (camera_x + screen_width) // tile_size

for y in range(min_y, max_y):
    for x in range(min_x, max_x):
        tile = tile_map[y][x]
        # Use the tile from the tilemap to blit whatever you want
        # Still must subtract camera_x and camera_y when positioning the rect
        pygame.draw.rect(....)
```

Alternatively, you could break the game into rooms, so only the tiles for the room the player is in have to be checked and blitted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  When I run your code, only one tile blits on the screen (when there is about 100).  I thought I put the screen_height and width too small but when I make them a lot more bigger I get a square made of tiles? I think I now the problem but I am not sure so I will ask: Should I use air tiles? Thanks!

Comment: @Pydude I guess for my solution to work, every position in the matrix has to be populated with a tile, or else the indexes wouldn't work. Some sort of air tile or blank tile would have to be used to fill the empty space.  Within the two for loops, try printing out y, x, and the position that tile is supposed to be in to see if it matches.